# VBA. To see which Column A entries do not appear in Column B

Tags: excel, vba, match

[image]

I am trying to write VBA code to determine which entries in column A do not appear in column B, and then print these entries.

```
 Sub Checker()
 Dim endrow As Integer

 endrow = 8


 For i = 2 To endrow

 Next i
 End Sub
```

I think the next step is to use an if statement with the worksheet function match, to first take the "345A" and compare it with each entry in Column B in turn.  But haven't any success implementing.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `COUNTIF` will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slow but thorough way:

```
Sub compareColumns()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim s As Range
    Dim firstCol As Range
    Dim secCol As Range

    Dim match As Boolean

    Set firstCol = Range("A1:A8")
    Set secCol = Range("B1:B8")

    For Each r In firstCol
        match = False

        For Each s In secCol
            If r.Value = s.Value Then
                match = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next s

    Debug.Print r.Address & "has a match = " & match

    Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long
LR = 8

For i = 2 To LR
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A" & i), Range("B:B")) = 0 Then
        Debug.Print Range("A" & i)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly! I have tried to run this but I am getting "Run time error '13': Type mismatch"  .   Any ideas please?

Comment: I may have swapped the criteria - AFK right now, can check in 30